# jQuery .on() click event seems to fire several times, even when binding to different buttons

Tags: jquery

I have been using the code below and its not acting as I am expecting. When I click on the next button it counts up, clicking on the back button counts down.

But then clicking next again skips a step of two. I am thinking of making this page even simpler but for my sanity was just wondering whats happening here.

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="tab">
    <h1>One</h1>

    <button id="one-back">Back</button>
    <button id="one-next">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="two" class="tab">
    <h1>Two</h1>

    <button id="two-back">Back</button>
    <button id="two-next">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="three" class="tab">
    <h1>Three</h1>

    <button id="three-back">Back</button>
    <button id="three-next">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="four" class="tab">
    <h1>Four</h1>

    <button id="four-back">Back</button>
    <button id="four-next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var checkout = {
     current: 0,
     init: function () {
        this.render();
     },
tab: [{
    id: 'one'
}, {
    id: 'two'
}, {
    id: 'three'
}, {
    id: 'four'
}],
render: function () {
    var self = this;
    $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id).show();

    $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id + '-back').on('click', function () {
        $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id).hide();

        if (self.current > 0) {
            self.current = self.current - 1;
        }

        self.render();
    });

    $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id + '-next').on('click', function () {
        $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id).hide();

        if (self.current <= 4) {
            self.current = self.current + 1;
        }

        self.render();
    });
}
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    checkout.init();
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjheath/HNdD7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are biding the handler multiple times by calling `self.render()` inside your click handlers. Use off() and on(), so it gets invoked that many number of times stepping it further.

```
$('#' + self.tab[self.current].id + '-back').off('click').on('click', function() {
```

and

```
$('#' + self.tab[self.current].id + '-back').off('click').on('click', function() {
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AUbMr/)**

You can probably do this way too, binding the handler against the class instead of id and seperating out the handler registration in another function.

```
var checkout = {
    current: 0,
    init: function () {
        this.render();
        this.registerHandlers();
    },
    registerHandlers: function () {
        var self = this;
        $('.back').on('click', function () {
            $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id).hide();
            if (self.current > 0) {
                self.current = self.current - 1;
            }

            self.render();
        });

        $('.next').on('click', function () {
            $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id).hide();
            if (self.current <= 4) {
                self.current = self.current + 1;
            }

            self.render();
        });
    },
    tab: [{
        id: 'one'
    }, {
        id: 'two'
    }, {
        id: 'three'
    }, {
        id: 'four'
    }],
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        $('#' + self.tab[self.current].id).show();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    checkout.init();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ327/)**